# Does tensorflow create a new numpy array each time it calls compute_gradients()?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

A typical training loop in tensorflow maybe as follows:

```
cg = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
grads = [None] * len(cg)
for gv in cg:
    grads[i] = gv[0]
# ... do some process to grads ...
apply_gradients = opt.apply_gradients(cg)
while (...):
    gradients = sess.run(grads)
    feed = dict()
    for i, grad_var in enumerate(cg)
        feed[grad_var[0]] = gradients[i]
    sess.run(apply_gradients, feed_dict=feed)
```

Each time it calls `sess.run(grads)`, a new numpy array `gradients` (with new-allocated inner memory) is generated. I want to use a fixed numpy array for all the training iterations, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tf.Optimizer.compute_gradients()` method should not create any new NumPy arrays: instead it builds a graph of TensorFlow operations for computing the gradients of the `loss` with respect to some or all of the variables in your model. The return value is not a NumPy array; it is a list of pairs of gradient `tf.Tensor` objects and the corresponding `tf.Variable` to which that gradient should be applied.

Nevertheless, it is usually wasteful of memory to call `opt.compute_gradients()` inside a loop. It's hard to say whether this will work exactly without seeing more of your code, but you should be able to move the call to `opt.compute_gradients()` before the loop, since it does not seem to depend on anything computed inside the loop. This will avoid building a new segment of TensorFlow graph in each loop iteration, and should reduce the memory cost.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear enough. I edited it, could you please give me some advice now? `gradients` now in my code is a numpy ndarray,  each time it is a new array. Can I use a array with a fixed pieces of memory in all the training iterations? How could I do that?

Comment: I got a idea. I think first I can write a python C extension,  which create a numpy array used a pinned memory. Then We edit the session run() implementation of tensorflow, let it use our own array, Then every time it executes `sess.run(grads)`, it will use a pinned memory.